# Правило редиректов в htaccess для отсечения параметров со знаком вопроса (?)

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Обращаюсь к Вам как к спецам, перерыл пол рунета, так и не нашел рабочего решения, как отсекать, удалять (перенаправлять автоматически) со всех урлов с параметром ? на главную страницу с чистым урлом.

```
https://rumate.ru/?escaped_fragment=-/c1o5f
https://rumate.ru/?escaped_fragment=untitled/c13sz
https://rumate.ru/?p=4426
и т.д.
```

редиректить на

```
https://rumate.ru/
```

Аналогично, для любых внутренних страниц, если можно.

Comment: А можно вопрос - для чего делать лишний редирект?

Comment: а потому что в яндекс.вебмастере куча дубликатов страниц, отдающих 200. это беда

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine On
# если строка запроса не пустая
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
# то 301 редирект на саму себя с удалением строки запроса
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://rumate.ru/$1? [R=301,L]
# а дальше остальные правила 
# ...
```

Comment: попробовал. действительно, когда на главной - все добавки с вопросом отрезает, но любая внутренняя страница переадресовывается также на главную rumate.ru/index.php

Comment: @Rumate.Ru, у вас в .htaccess еще что-то прописано?

Comment: AddDefaultCharset utf-8
<Files ".htaccess">
deny from all
</Files>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.rumate.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://rumate.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://rumate.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html

Comment: @Rumate.Ru, изменил ответ.

Comment: нет, схема нерабочая.

Comment: @Rumate.Ru, удалите все остальные редиректы из .htaccess, очистите кеш у своего браузера (чтобы убрать закешированные редиректы) или откройте сайт в другом браузере (в котором редиректы не сохранялись) для проверки.

Comment: удалил, почистил, проверил. удалил вообще всё кроме предложенного. С любой страницы перекидывает на /index.php